# Characterize the limit spectrum of the matrix $Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Suppose the following matrix relationship
$$Y_{m\times n}=A_{m\times k}B_{k\times n}+C_{m\times n} \quad \quad (*)$$

holds for all $m,n$ and some fixed $k$. Assume that

$(1)$ $\frac{1}{m}A'A\to\Sigma_A $ as $m\to \infty$ and $\frac{1}{n}BB'\to\Sigma_B$ as $n\to \infty$ for some positive definite $k\times k$ matrices $\Sigma_A,\Sigma_B $, where convergence is with respect to the Frobenius norm.

$(2)$ $\lambda_1(\frac{1}{nm}CC')\to 0$ as $m,n\to\infty$, where $\lambda_1$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of the matrix.

Am trying to prove the following result:

**Proposition.** The $k$ largest eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{mn}YY'$ converge to the eigenvalues of $\Sigma_A\Sigma_B$ as $m,n\to \infty$. All other eigenvalues converge to zero.

**Proof.** Using Weyl's inequalities for singular values and $(*)$ we obtain

$$\sigma_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} Y\bigg)\leq \sigma_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} AB\bigg) +\sigma_1\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} C\bigg)$$

$$\sigma_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} AB\bigg)\leq \sigma_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} Y\bigg) +\sigma_1\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} C\bigg)$$

for $i=1,\dots,\min\{m,n\}$, where $\sigma_i$ denotes the $i$th largest singular value the matrix. Combining both inequalities gives

$$\Bigg|\sigma_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} Y\bigg)-\sigma_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} AB\bigg)\Bigg|\leq\sigma_1\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} C\bigg) \quad \quad (**)$$

We have $\sigma_1\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} C\bigg)=\lambda^{1/2}_1\bigg(\frac{1}{mn} CC'\bigg)\to 0$ as $m,n\to\infty$ by $(2)$. Moreover, since the rank of $AB$ is at most $k$, we have $\sigma_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} AB\bigg)=0$ for $i>k$. Therefore from $(**)$ we directly get that $\lambda_i\bigg(\frac{1}{mn} YY'\bigg)=\sigma^2_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} Y\bigg)\to 0$ as $m,n\to \infty$ for $i>k$.

Next fix $i\leq k$. Since $$\sigma^2_i\bigg(\Sigma^{1/2}_A \Sigma^{1/2}_B\bigg)=\lambda_i\bigg(\Sigma^{1/2}_A \Sigma_B\Sigma^{1/2}_A\bigg)=\lambda_i\bigg(\Sigma_A \Sigma_B\bigg)$$

and in view of $(**)$ it suffices to show that $\sigma^2_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} AB\bigg)\to\sigma^2_i\bigg(\Sigma^{1/2}_A \Sigma^{1/2}_B\bigg) $ as $m,n\to \infty$.

Now, $$\sigma^2_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} AB\bigg)=\lambda_i\bigg(\frac{1}{mn} B'A'AB\bigg)=\lambda_i\bigg(\frac{1}{mn} A'ABB'\bigg)=\lambda_i\bigg( (\frac{1}{n}BB')^{1/2}(\frac{1}{m}A'A) (\frac{1}{n}BB')^{1/2}\bigg)$$

Using $(1)$ and the inequality from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1840936/522332) we have $(\frac{1}{n}BB')^{1/2}\to \Sigma^{1/2}_B $. Therefore by continuity of matrix multiplication and of eigenvalues on the space of symmetric real matrices we get

$$\sigma^2_i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} AB\bigg)\to\lambda_i (\Sigma_B^{1/2}\Sigma_A \Sigma_B^{1/2})=\sigma^2_i(\Sigma^{1/2}_A \Sigma^{1/2}_B)$$

as $m,n\to \infty$, as desired.

Is this correct? Is there a more efficient way to proceed in the last step?